# json object in php

Tags: java, php, json, gson

I am sending a json object from java to php. I am using gson in java side which sends json as an object:

Java code:

```
Fruit fruit = new Fruit();
fruit.setFruidId(6);
fruit.setAvailable("yes yes");

Gson gson = new Gson();
String json = gson.toJson(fruit);
```

This json string look like this

```
{"fruidId":6,"available":"yes yes"}
```

Using java side I can retrieve the json data as an object like this

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
Fruit a = gson.fromJson(json, Fruit.class);
System.out.println(fruit.getFruitId());
```

I want to retrieve the data in php as an object; like the one I have done using java.
Is it possible to do it like this? Please show me the way.

Comment: See [json_encode()](http://php.net/json_encode) and [json_decode()](http://php.net/json_encode)

Comment: No you can't do it like in java, because PHP is not java. But you might find [`json_decode`](http://php.net/json_decode) helpful. But it can't create a `Fruit` out of the json string. Are you especially concerned about that?

Comment: Yes I wanted to create Fruit object out of json string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [json_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) with the 2nd paramater as `false` to set to an object or `true` as an array.

Comment: How to make it return the `Fruit` object as in the java code?

Comment: $json = '{"fruitId":6,"available":"yes yes"}';
    $object = json_decode($json);
    echo $object->fruitId;

Comment: I want to call like this $fruit->getFruitId()... not $object->fruitId
If it is not possible to do it like this that I guess I need forget this object technique

Comment: PHP doesn't have getters and setters, unless you implement it into your class. But if you just want to get the fruit id, why $object->fruitId is not good?

Answer (score 0):

if u send the same JSON object as above to a php server via post method, then it can be decoded using php as

$json = $_SERVER['HTTP_JSON'];

$data = json_decode($json);

$name = $data->fruitId;

$pos = $data->Available;

that should do it.